# Cannot get PUT parameter Phalcon Oauth2 server

Tags: php, api, rest, oauth, phalcon

I have a problem to get PUT request data.

I follow this skeleton project :
[Phalcon-api-oauth2](https://github.com/goors/phalcon-api-oauth2)

when I send PUT request,
the result always empty array()

I have tried changed the several code :

micro.php 

 before

```
public function setRoutes($file) {
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        throw new \Exception('Unable to load routes file');
    }
    $routes = include($file);
    if (!empty($routes)) {
        foreach($routes as $obj) {
            switch($obj['method']) {
                case 'get':
                    $this->get($obj['route'], $obj['handler']);
                    break;
                case 'post':
                    $this->post($obj['route'], $obj['handler']);
                    break;
                case 'delete':
                    $this->delete($obj['route'], $obj['handler']);
                    break;
                case 'put':
                    $this->head($obj['route'], $obj['handler']);
                    break;
                case 'options':
                    $this->options($obj['route'], $obj['handler']);
                    break;
                case 'patch':
                    $this->patch($obj['route'], $obj['handler']);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

after

```
public function setRoutes($file) {
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        throw new \Exception('Unable to load routes file');
    }
    $routes = include($file);
    if (!empty($routes)) {
        foreach($routes as $obj) {
            switch($obj['method']) {
                case 'get':
                    $this->get($obj['route'], $obj['handler']);
                    break;
                case 'post':
                    $this->post($obj['route'], $obj['handler']);
                    break;
                case 'delete':
                    $this->delete($obj['route'], $obj['handler']);
                    break;
                case 'put':
                    $this->put($obj['route'], $obj['handler']);
                    break;
                case 'options':
                    $this->options($obj['route'], $obj['handler']);
                    break;
                case 'patch':
                    $this->patch($obj['route'], $obj['handler']);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added new method for PUT request in
 vendor/Oauth2/src/Oauth2/Server/Storage/Pdo/Mysql/Request.php

```
public function put($index = NULL)
{
    // print_r($this->request->getPut()); // I can see the PUT request data here
    return $this->request->getPut($index);
}
```

also added in 
vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/League/OAuth2/Server/Util/RequestInterface.php

```
 public function put($index = null);
```

then modified this class 
vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/League/OAuth2/Server/Util/Request.php

```
class Request implements RequestInterface
{
protected $get = array();
protected $post = array();
protected $cookies = array();
protected $files = array();
protected $server = array();
protected $headers = array();
protected $put = array(); // new property added

// new $put parameter added */
public function __construct(array $get = array(), array $post = array(), array $put = array(), array $cookies = array(), array $files = array(), array $server = array(), $headers = array())
{
    $this->get = $get;
    $this->post = $post;
    $this->put = $put;
    $this->cookies = $cookies;
    $this->files = $files;
    $this->server = $server;

    if (empty($headers)) {
        $this->headers = $this->readHeaders();
    } else {
        $this->headers = $this->normalizeHeaders($headers);
    }
}

/* new method added */
public function put($index = null, $default = null)
{
    return $this->getPropertyValue('put', $index, $default);
}

....
```

can anyone please let me know what wrong with the code ?

Cheers.

Comment: Is it a case sensitivity problem?

Comment: @JamesFenwick I don't think so, It's seems oauth server's library replacing the real value of getPut() functions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to change the `Content-Type` of the `PUT` request?

I had a similar problem with `PUT` parameters and it was solved by using `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Try to add it to the headers array of the `Request` class.